# MySQL regex searching on a column

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to do a MySQL search on a column with this regex pattern:

`/\w.*\s(Metro)\s\d{2}[-]\d{4}/g`

[image]

So my MySQL query is:

```
SELECT vehicle_plate_number 
from users 
where vehicle_plate_number REGEXP '\w.*\s(Metro)\s\d{2}[-]\d{4}'
```

I have like 7 thousand entries with matching pattern but MySQL is returning zero results. Can't seem to detect the mistake here.

Comment: You should always indicate what version of MySQL you are using, since MySQL 8 started using ICU regex library that is much more powerful than the POSIX regex it used before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's `REGEXP` has its own particular syntax.  It doesn't support `\s`, `\d`, or `\w`, but we can still approximate these.  Here is a version of your pattern which seems to work:

```
SELECT vehicle_plate_number 
FROM users 
WHERE vehicle_plate_number REGEXP '[a-z0-9].*[[:space:]]Metro[[:space:]][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{4}';
```

### Demo

Comment: Note that what I wrote isn' t a literal translation of your original pattern, but it is close and likely what you intend.